# How to make 1 row by grouping in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-400

I have a question from my sql script in DB2.

```
SELECT a.fcyfdtaid current_id_book, a.fcyyyymm current_month_book, a.fcyaccsts current_quality_book, a.fcyarrmth current_dpd, 
b.fcyfdtaid old_id_book, b.fcyyyymm old_month_book, b.fcyaccsts old_quality_book, b.fcyarrmth old_dpd 
FROM crbidnpd.entfcym0 a JOIN crbidnpd.entfcym0 b 
ON a.fcyfdtaid = b.fcyfdtaid AND 
b.fcyarrmth < a.fcyarrmth AND 
a.fcyyyymm='201911'  AND a.fcyarrmth>10
where NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT b.fcyfdtaid old_id_book FROM crbidnpd.entfcym0 c 
WHERE c.fcyfdtaid = a.fcyfdtaid AND c.fcyyyymm = a.fcyyyymm AND c.fcyyyymm = b.fcyyyymm) order by a.fcydtaid;
```

and the result

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyvBR.png)

how to make it being one row that displays in the last 2 years, on the left 2011 and on the right only 2010?

Comment: Please, do not post images here. It's better to provide your initial result set in the form of `select * from (values (..., ...), (..., ...)) t (col1, ..., coN)` and the exact result desired.

Comment: Make it easy - and possible - to assist you: [mcve].